# mybatis delete mapper get param from object

Tags: java, mybatis

How can I define my mapper for delete action for some object.
For example, something like this:

```
@Delete("delete from customer c where c.id = #{customerID:INTEGER} ")

public void delete(Customer customer);
```

Is something like that possible?

When I try something like that I get exception while running test:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found):

Comment: Try yourself and see what is the error

Comment: i'm sorry , i did not write exception:)
I will edit my first post

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is a get/set method for customerID in your Customer class.

Otherwise, please post your Customer class for us to help you.